# Securing API for a Frontend Website

Tags: rest, security

Our APIs (delivered by a third party) are using Tokens in order to ensure authorized access only. Our new website should not be server-to-server but mostly front end, i.e. the token would be visible in the script. We're now checking how to secure the API for a frontend website and I have to propose ways to my boss. However, I've never had to do something with API securing, could you please help me by telling me where to read / state of the art solutions?

I've already begun to look into OAuth1a, OAuth2, OpenID but can't (yet) really get a direction to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You should still use a token, but you have to make sure that the token doesn't grant you full access to the API.

Tokens need to be specific to the user who's using the application, and the token can only grant API access to the specific functions that the user is allowed to do.

For now I would ignore OAuth1 and OpenID and *only* look at OAuth2. There's enough features there to do what you want, and it's simpler than the rest.